# bash: read line by line and store each line into different variables

Tags: bash, file, variables, line

I've got a file that contains the following 3 lines:

```
NAME
ANOTHER NAME
NUMBER
```

I need a bash script that stores line 1 into the `$var1`, line 2 into `$var2` and line 3 into `$var3`.

Comment: So what have you tried so far?  Maybe enter `bash tutorial` into your search engine?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array and refer to each line as myarray[0], myarray[1], etc.

```
$ readarray -t myarray < file
```

To see what the array contains use

```
declare -p myarray
```